# Adding bullet-like buttons to scrolling slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

So I want to add bullet-like buttons at the bottom of the slideshow, but I can't find a tutorial, so thought you guys could help me out. Here is an example: http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/jquery-slideshow/demo/index.html

Comment: `border-radius:50%` will make an element circular

Comment: @Jashwant but how do i create these buttons? and i need a script i guess

Comment: What slider are you using?

Comment: @RokasStankaitis, this is not a `do-my-homework` website. You should know how to create a button. Or I can refer some links to read about creating buttons. If you need to make them circular, then add `border-radius:50%`

Comment: @Jashwant yes, i know, its just i don't know how to do it, im ASKing for help, not demanding it

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS background on your links:

```
<a href="..." class="someClass">...</a>
```

CSS:

```
.someClass {
    background-image:url(/images/...);   <--path to your image
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;   <--- set sizes to match your image.
}
```

Comment: I need to create these bullet-like buttons with gimp or something and then add them to this line:
    background-image:url(/images/...);   <--path to your image

Comment: Yes. You can create as many classes as you want, each with its own image. If you want to get more advanced, you can combine icons into a single file and use CSS sprites: http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-articles/an-introduction-to-css-sprites.html

Comment: Generate them as PNG files.